# What kind of adverbs can modify another adverb?

Tags: adverbs

> 1. There's a huge market ***out there***.
> 2. The book is ***over there***.

In the first sentence, what does "out there" mean? "out" is an adverb,does it modify "there"?
If I want to divide the sentence into different parts, which in the following is right?

> There/ is /a huge market/ out there.
>
> There/ is /a huge market/ out ***/*** there.

In the second sentence, "over" is an adverb, does it modify "there"?

Comment: What do you know about prepositions?

Comment: @Jim The noun( phrase) or the noun clause should be placed behind the preposition. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 4):

The construction *preposition + "there"* is informal and probably fairly recent. Or perhaps it is better to speak of three different constructions, because the meaning of each one is not based on the meaning of the preposition in the same way.

> There's a huge market out there.

It is best to think of **out there** as a fixed phrase. It means something like "in a place outside". If you would have to analyse it, perhaps you could say it is like a double adverb. The word *out* is used adverbially to mean "outside", which is generally possible; the word *there* is an adverb meaning "away from me, the speaker". So then the compound meaning would be "outside and some distance away from me/us". That is more or less what the phrase means, I would say. Derived from this is the figurative meaning "eccentric, strange" for a person: *she is really out there*.

> The book is over there.

The phrase **over there** is also informal and probably best treated as a set phrase. It means more or less the same as *there*. The word *over* is more generally used in informal language with locations: *let's go over to my place, she is over at my place*. It adds very little meaning to those sentences—perhaps an added sense of "removed from the speaker", derived from phrases like *over the river, over the ocean*. Similarly, it adds little meaning to *there* is *over there*. You could say it is used like some sort of particle or adverb to emphasise *there*, but it is really impossible to analyse. The same applies to *over here*.

> There are people in there.

The phrase **in there** is, again, probably best considered a set phrase meaning "inside that place", for instance inside a house or inside a box. It is slightly informal. You could say *in* is used adverbially, similar to *is father in?*, which means "is father in the house?". Or you could say it is a preposition that treats *there* like a noun meaning "that place": "inside that place". While *there* is not normally a noun and normally does not take a preposition, it still seems to be like that in this case. Relative pronouns of location can sometimes also do something with prepositions, as in *the place from whence she came* or *from where she came*, or *wherein* (legal language).

> From there you need to take the train to Oxford.

The phrase **from there** can be analysed the same way as *in there*, as *preposition + noun*, where *there* means "that place". In *from here*, the word *here* would then mean "this place". The phrase does not sound informal at all to me, which may indicate that it is an older phrase than the ones above.

> Go from here to there.

The phrase **to there** clearly seems to be constructed as *preposition + noun*. In this context, at least, it does not sound especially informal; but in most cases you would just say *there* (not *to there*) when it immediately follows a verb: *she went there* is normal, not <s>she went to there</s>.

As you see, not all of these phrases seem to be of the same kind. The last three are more like *preposition + noun*, the first two are perhaps different.

Comment: Define "recent": http://history1900s.about.com/od/1910s/a/overtheresong.htm ;-)

Comment: @Jim: Right, maybe after 1800? It all depends on your definition, as you say... I believe phrases can remain "colloquial" for centuries without becoming part of formal language. So it is hard to predict how old an expression is that is currently felt to be colloquial.

Comment: I guess I've never thought of "over there" as colloquial- *Over here* and *over there* are so just so frequently used, and while I don't think I've ever used them in formal writing I think that has more to do with the fact that I've never needed to tan because I didn't think they belonged there.

Comment: @Jim: But you will probably agree that *over there* is not quite the same as *from there*? Of course it all depends on the speaker, but I don't think there will be anyone who would consider *from there* even slightly informal.

Answer (score 0):

I would see such where-indications of the type "up there, down there, in here" etc simply  as two-part adverbs.  Your way of looking at such combinations will get you into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Those that change the quality or degree of the other adverb.

For instance, if we describe *the manner in which* something happens then we may also restrict or qualify that manner.

> He watched the time closely.

and

> He watched the time *very* closely.

Here you can see what is plainly an adverb, *closely*, and it is modified by the adverb *very*.